# Confused about call func on the same column multiple times in Spark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I know that `RDDs` should be `cache()` if they will be used multiple times later.

But how about DataFrame?

Thinking of this case:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('1', ['a', 'B']), ('2', ['C', 'd'])], ['idx', 'item'])
res = df.select(df['idx'], *[upper(df['item'][i]) for i in range(2)])
```

I call `upper` on column `df['item']` twice.

Does `df` generate again when doing `upper` the second time?

Should I call `cache()` on `df`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to cache - your code accesses `df` only once. Referencing column:

```
df['item'][i]
```

doesn't require any computation on the data.